# postmaster caused kernel hung issue

Tags: postgresql, linux-kernel, kernel

I have one server which has below kernel logs in /var/log/messages, looks postgres db process postmaster caused the kernel hung issue, any clues to confirm that? and any actions can prevent this issue happen?

```
2014-10-22T05:35:29.140-05:00 localhost kernel: BUG: Bad page state in process postmaster  pfn:42bfbd
2014-10-22T05:35:29.140-05:00 localhost kernel: page:ffffea000e99f158 flags:00c0000000000000 count:-1 mapcount:0 mapping:(null) index:20c53e (Not tainted)
2014-10-22T05:35:29.140-05:00 localhost kernel: Pid: 9543, comm: postmaster Not tainted 2.6.32-358.23.2.el6.x86_64 #1
2014-10-22T05:35:29.140-05:00 localhost kernel: Call Trace:
2014-10-22T05:35:29.140-05:00 localhost kernel: [<ffffffff81128f37>] ? bad_page+0x107/0x160
2014-10-22T05:35:29.140-05:00 localhost kernel: [<ffffffff8112a73c>] ? get_page_from_freelist+0x72c/0x830
2014-10-22T05:35:29.140-05:00 localhost kernel: [<ffffffff8112bc43>] ? __alloc_pages_nodemask+0x113/0x8d0
2014-10-22T05:35:29.140-05:00 localhost kernel: [<ffffffff8112fe00>] ? __lru_cache_add+0x40/0x90
2014-10-22T05:35:29.140-05:00 localhost kernel: [<ffffffff81143c27>] ? handle_pte_fault+0x487/0xb50
2014-10-22T05:35:29.140-05:00 localhost kernel: [<ffffffff81160c6a>] ? alloc_pages_current+0xaa/0x110
```

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely not a Postgres problem — it's a kernel bug or hardware issue. You use an outdated (and insecure) kernel — `yum update` your server and reboot — if it's a bug than it may be corrected in latest kernel release and your issue may go away.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but is there any proof from the log to identify it is a kernel bug?

Comment: Could be a hardware failure (disk or memory), even spikes or bad contacts. Since the DBMS is a big resource consumer (memory and disk), the chances are big that the DBMS will "cause" such a failure. The other probable "cause" is the swapfile (if any), which also can have high traffic.